# Parameter 0 of constructor required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

My springboot application fails to start with below error:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.mydump.digital.aws.ParameterStore required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.

I can see both the values "ssm.preset-path" and "amazon.aws.region" configured in my application.yml file.
Please help what is going wrong here ?

springboot 3.1.1
gradle 8.1.1

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ParameterStore {

    @Value("${ssm.preset-path}")
    private String presetPath;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.region}")
    private String region;

    @Autowired
    private SsmClient ssmClient;

    private static List<Parameter> parameterList;

    public ParameterStore() {
    }

    public List<String> getParameterConfiguration(final String preset) {
       /*
       some code
       */
    }

    //read aws ssm parameters store and get all parameters by path
    public void populatePresetParameters() {
        parameterList = ssmClient.getParametersByPath(request -> request.path(presetPath)).parameters();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you added AllArgsConstructor, it will include all the member fields in the constructor including your @Value fields. Change the `AllArgsConstructor` to `RequiredArgsConstructor`.  In this case, Lombok will generate a constructor based on 'required' final fields as arguments.

Replace this if you want to use constructor injection:

```
@Autowired
    private SsmClient ssmClient;
```

with

```
private final SsmClient ssmClient;
```

Finally make sure that the properties `ssm.preset-path` and `amazon.aws.region` are defined application.properties.